# F# TypeShape - This code is not sufficiently generic

Tags: f#

I'm trying to learn the [TypeShape](https://github.com/eiriktsarpalis/TypeShape) lib and playing with the `IShapeMember` per the snippet in the readme

> type IShapeMember<'DeclaringType, 'Field> =
> abstract Get : 'DeclaringType -> 'Field
> abstract Set : 'DeclaringType -> 'Field -> 'DeclaringType

Here is my code in an effort to generalise a 'setter' function

```
let setMemberValue (value: 'b) (target: 'c) (shp: IShapeMember<'c>) =
    shp.Accept { new IMemberVisitor<'c,'c> with
        member x.Visit (m: ShapeMember<'c,'b>) = m.Set target value}
```

But this gives me the compile error: *This code is not sufficiently generic. The type variable 'a could not be generalized because it would escape its scope.*

(btw, that's not a type on the error, it indeed complains about variable 'a....)

I have tried all manner of Type wrangling but cannot get my head around what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a TypeShape expert, but I think the problem here is that you're not honoring the signature of the `Visit` function, which is:

```ml
type IMemberVisitor<'TRecord, 'R> =
    abstract Visit<'Field> : ShapeMember<'TRecord, 'Field> -> 'R
```

Note that the `'Field` type parameter is determined by whoever calls `Visit`, not by you. Thus, your attempt to use the external `value` in the call to `Set` isn't sufficiently generic. Instead, you need a way to obtain an instance of `'Field` from *within* the `Visit` function, so it works with whatever `'Field` type the caller desires. This is easier said than done, but if you want a trivial example to start with, this will compile at least:

```ml
let visitor target =
    {
        new IMemberVisitor<'TRecord, 'R> with
            member x.Visit (m: ShapeMember<'TRecord,'Field>) =
                let value = Unchecked.defaultof<'Field>
                let target' = m.Set target value
                Unchecked.defaultof<'R>
    }
```

There's also an example of calling `Set` from within `Visit` [here](https://github.com/eiriktsarpalis/TypeShape/blob/4187e3243aba9a146a3e9013e82df414d69951e8/samples/TypeShape.Samples/iso.fs#L42), but it is more complex. I don’t think there is any way of doing it that is both simple and useful.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, I was not thinking about it in the right way, have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
let setMemberValue (value: 'b) (target: 'c) (shp: IShapeMember<'c>) =
    shp.Accept { new IMemberVisitor<'c,'c> with
        member x.Visit (m: ShapeMember<'c,'d>) = 
            if typeof<'b> = typeof<'a> then //or convert 'b -> 'd function
                m.Set target (box value :?> 'd)
            else 
                failwith "The supplied type does not match the type of the target field"
                }
```

Boxing and casting the supplied `value` to the type `'d` did the trick. All wrapped in some form of type check in case the caller supplied value does not match that of the field being set

Comment: Hmm, is this really a solution? It seems to defeat the purpose of type shapes. But if you're happy, I'm happy.

Comment: I assume you mean 'defeating the purpose of TypeShapes', by virtue of the value no longer being type safe ? You are probably right that this is not a solution. You made me think about it more but swimming beyond my knowledge. The boxing did solve my immediate problem, but I be happy to take on board option from anyone else landing here with the know how.